# Method bound to checked attribute of angular mat-checkbox is triggered multiple times

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5, angular-material2

I have a nested JSON array through which I'm iterating to display data. Each object is rendered as a checkbox, and if the value associated with the nested option called 'checked' is true, checkbox is checked. And if the field is unchecked 'checked' option is set false.
Below is the HTML code and sample JSON with one object:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let dm of data; let lst = last; let midx = index;">
  <mat-expansion-panel class="mar-bot-1">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{dm.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <section>
      <div *ngFor="let fd of dm.fields; let lst = last; let fst = first; let fidx = index;">
        <div class="row pad-left-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="primary" [checked]="checkSelected(midx, fidx)" (change)="onFieldChange(midx, fidx, $event)"
                [disabled]="fd.field.required" disableRipple>
                {{fd.field.fieldname}}
                <span *ngIf="fd.field.required" matTooltip="This field is required" style="color:#dc3545;">*</span>
                </mat-checkbox> &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</ng-container>
```

JSON:

```
data : [
    {   
        name: 'ABC',
        description: ''
        fields: [
            {
                field: {
                    fieldname: 'field1'
                    required: true
                },
                options: [
                    { field: {
                        fieldname: 'checked',
                        fieldtype: boolean,
                        fieldvalue: true
                      }
                    },
                    { field: {
                        fieldname: 'someoption'
                        fieldtype: string,
                        fieldvalue: 'maybestring'
                      }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: {
                    fieldname: 'field2'
                    required: false
                },
                options: [
                    { field: {
                        fieldname: 'checked',
                        fieldtype: boolean,
                        fieldvalue: false
                      }
                    },
                    { field: {
                        fieldname: 'someoption2'
                        fieldtype: string,
                        fieldvalue: 'maybestring'
                      }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When the page loads, checkbox is ticked by default by binding it to a method `checkSelected()` and on change onFieldChange() is called.

```
checkSelected(midx, fidx) {
    //iterate over data and look for fieldvalue of checked option and return the value
}

onFieldChange(midx, fidx, $event) {
    //Iterate over data and set value as per the event to checked option
}
```

But the issue is checkedSelected() is called multiple times on page load / open or close expansion panel / when checkbox is checked which calls onFieldChange().

I'm sure that there is no hidden calls being made to checkedSelected(), but somehow it is called multiple times (**for entire object - iterating over each field**) leading to `expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` whenever I try setting some flags (required for other logic).

if anybody could guide me to understand why is a function bound to an attribute is triggered multiple times and how to fix it! Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Whenever a change is detected and the template rendered, that method will be called to determine what the return value is. Maybe you should look for help on how to not get the `expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` from happening. You'd have to post more details about your code for assistance on that though.

Comment: Thank you @DanielWStrimpel, much appreciated. It would be helpful to understand how to overcome the multiple calls, because according me my code does pretty much simpler tasks. Once if that is in place, I should be able to fix `expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. Please let me know if there are any links which I could follow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding `[checked]` and `(change)`, use `[(ngModel)]` instead -
 something like `[(ngModel)]="fd.options[0].field.fieldvalue"`.

Comment: Problem with that is - more fields might get added to options array and also possible chance of reordering the objects in backend as per the project need. So I cannot have a hardcoded index attached with ngModel

Comment: Then it really just depends on how you are implementing `checkSelected` and `onFieldChange`. There is no reason why it can't work, but you haven't shown your code for those functions. [Here is a stackblitz using your code with my own implementations of the checked and change functions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjeezr) which works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your patience! Your approach is very similar to mine, but if you check your code, `checkSelected` is called multiple times when the expansion panel is toggled or any checkbox is checked. Please check the console.log() messages, that's exactly is my issue.

Comment: I don't think that's an issue - that's Angular :) I don't think it's possible to control or predict when or how often Angular polls for changes. If this is the only "problem" you are facing, I suggest ignoring it. If you are having real performance issues - it is probably due to the way you are implementing the check, not the fact that the check occurs a few times more than you think it should happen when you open and close the expansion panel. However, it might still be worthwhile to check Angular on GitHub for related issues.